# Creating a return type of a recursive method

Tags: java, jsp, recursion, arraylist

I have the following recursive method that generates permutations for a given string. I am trying to create a return type for the generated strings in an arraylist, more specifically I am trying to printout the out put in a jsp page.

```
 public static void permutation(String str) { 
      permutation("", str); 
 }

private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
     int n = str.length();
     if (n == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
     else {
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+ n));
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm having really hard time figuring out what you mean by "create a return type".

Comment: @ChrisMartin He means that he wants to return something from `permutation` instead of just returning `void`. However, I'm still not sure exactly what that should be.

Comment: you wanna have a return type to be used later within a servlet, like putting those resulting strings in an arraylist of object..ect

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Permute {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findAllPermutations("abc"));
    }

    public static List<String> findAllPermutations(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (s.length() <= 1) {
            return Arrays.asList(s);
        }

        List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permutation : findAllPermutations(s.substring(1))) {
            char ch = s.charAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i <= permutation.length(); i++) {
                String prefix = permutation.substring(0, i);
                String suffix = permutation.substring(i);
                permutations.add(prefix + ch + suffix);
            }
        }
        return permutations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static list to "collect" the results:

```
static List<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    permutation("abc");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(perms.toArray())); // prints [abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba]
}

public static void permutation(String str) {
    permutation("", str);
}

private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) {
        perms.add(prefix);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1)); // you had a bug in the last index on this line
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create the list and pass it as an argument:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();
    permutation("abc", perms);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(perms.toArray())); // print [abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba]
}

public static void permutation(String str, List<String> perms) {
    permutation("", str, perms);
}

private static void permutation(String prefix, String str, List<String> perms) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) {
        perms.add(prefix);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1), perms);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. It's a really bad idea to construct/store a method's return value using a global variable.

Comment: @JimN First, I provided a second way of doing it (without using a static member). Second, the reason I provided the first approach was to solve the issue with minimum code changes (methods signature etc). And third, if all the work that is done in this class is create the permutations once in a lifetime of an unthreaded program, then using a static field, in this case, would be perfectly fine.